# VB: Object variable or With block variable not set - why?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get my VB app to write to a database if a check box is selected simple 1 to indicate yes, all rows in the DB are currently set to 0. 
THis seems to be the line of code that its pointing to and suggesting that 'Object variable or With block variable not set'
I am a complete newbie with this thing...

```
   sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbSelect", cbSelect.Checked) 'passing the @chkBox parameter to the command
```

here is the code behind.

```
Protected Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows 'itterate tru all rows
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("cbSelect"), CheckBox) 'find the checkBox inside GridView
        Dim sqlcon As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SYD-PB0FW9M\blah;Initial Catalog=Support_Metrics;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=reportserver;Password=xxxxxxxx")
        Dim sqlComm As New SqlCommand("insert into contacted values (@cbSelect)", sqlcon) 'this is an insert example, you can do update you can get the current gridView row id using gvRow.Cells(0).Text
        sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbSelect", cbSelect.Checked) 'passing the @cbSelect parameter to the command
        Using (sqlcon)
            sqlcon.Open() 'open connection
            sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery() 'execute the command
        End Using
    Next
End Sub
```

here is the ASPX:

```
  <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="False" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" Checked="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="account_id" HeaderText="account_id" SortExpression="account_id" />
```

Comment: what is `cbSelect`? did you mean `chkBox` in the stead?

Comment: Did and edit with more context - was right this is the ID.

Comment: Well, looking at the code here you seem to be trying to call for a property of an object you're not instantiating. I believe in your code you mean to be calling `sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbSelect", chkBox.Checked)`

Comment: Adrian nicely done. thank you

Comment: Well, since that was the correct answer I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looking at the code here you seem to be trying to call for a property of an object you're not instantiating. I believe in your code you mean to be calling

```
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cbSelect", chkBox.Checked)
```